# how to use abp repository in global.aspx?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5, aspnetboilerplate

In the mvc5 project, I want to take database data fill in Redis at `Application_Start`. but at that time `IocManager` registration not completed. What should I do to solve this problem (don't use ADO.Net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can feed your Redis application in **PostInitialize** method of **WebMvcModule.cs** class.

In the sample code, I am retrieving users from the database.

```cs
public override void PostInitialize()
{
    var userRepository = IocManager.Resolve<IRepository<User, long>>();
    var users = userRepository.GetAllList();
    /* Feed the Redis here... */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! it's very useful! but i have another question. i can't use *Linq to SQL* like this `repository.GetAll().GroupBy(p => p.CityCode).Select(p => p.Key).ToList()` in *PostInitialize*?

Comment: maybe you miss to import some namespace. see what is included in imports in the class where you can successfully run GetAll()